# Can't remember which partition Ubuntu is on

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Basically, I'm dual-booting windows 10 with Ubuntu, but for the life of me I can't remember which partition it's on.

I ran the disk management tool, and it showed these results.

[image: disk management tool screenshot]

Normally I'd be able to tell, however on this laptop it has a recovery partition on drive D: (although I only have one HDD inside of it, if that helps)

I'm assuming it is the 11.64gb / 7.92gb partitions but I don't want to make an assume and mess up the boot.

Screenshots:
[image: GParted]

Apologies if the formatting isn't very good, I've never used this website before.

Resuts of `lsblk -i`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
`-sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
|-sda4   8:4    0   860M  0 part 
|-sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part 
|-sda7   8:7    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
|-sda5   8:5    0  20.4G  0 part 
|-sda3   8:3    0 890.4G  0 part 
|-sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part 
`-sda6   8:6    0  11.6G  0 part
```

[edit] 
I also forgot to mention in the original post that I ran os-uninstaller to uninstall the ubuntu OS. I probably should've mentioned this but my mind blanked.

Comment: post the result of `sudo lsblk -i`

Comment: You could try mounting the partitions so you can have a look at what's on them.  That should give you an idea.

Comment: I added the results of lsblk, wasn't able to screenshot I can only add 2 images.

Comment: If you install grub, it should detect Windows as well as Ubuntu automatically, and create the menus for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu partition would be formatted in ext4, but none of your screenshots show one.

I would guess it was installed on the 11.61GB partition, and OS-Uninstaller formatted it as NTFS. You can go back to Windows, delete the 11.6GB and 7.9GB partitions, and expand C into the empty space. (The 7.9GB partition was Ubuntu's swap space.)

Comment: I used os-uninstaller to get rid of the ubuntu installation. but it still shows that the partition exists. Could this be why? I feel I Should've mentioned this.

Comment: I deleted my comments since I've incorporated them into my answer.

Comment: Just wanted to say this worked. Is there any way to add this answer as solved?

Comment: @Pauleen yes, you can click the check mark next to the arrows to mark the answer as "accepted".