# How can I check which partition contains Ubuntu intstallation, using Gparted while in live USB of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, gparted

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my machine.

Now I want to check from live USB using Gparted or the `df` command which partition contains my Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

I am getting a `/` value output under `mounted on`, `aufs` as coordinate parameters and i am not sure which partition `aufs` refers to.

[image: SCREENSHOT of gparted and df]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Usually the partition of ext4 type contains Ubuntu. Also, the partitions beside which key can be seen indicates that these partitions are currently in use. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: what Kind of key are you saying Kulfy ?

Comment: The kind of small key that show in GParted after sda2 and sda6. That means "locked" because in use.

Comment: Ubuntu is on sda2, Windows is on sda3, Games on sda4 and Movies on sda5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which partition is Ubuntu installed on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527863/how-to-know-which-partition-is-ubuntu-installed-on) and [Can't remember which partition Ubuntu is on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894072/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### By Elimination:

The only partitions with enough used space to contain operating systems are sda2 and sda3.

Ubuntu does not install on NTFS so it must be on sda2.

Windows does not install on ext4 so it must be on sda3.

Just guessing about Games and Movies but the labels seem right.